# How can I change the css file names with jQuery ? (example: "file2.css" change "file1.css")

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
var mobile = (/iphone|ipad|ipod|android|blackberry|mini|windows\sce|palm/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()))

if(mobile){
     <link href="mobil.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">            
}
else {
         <link href="nonmobil.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">     
    }
```

Comment: Explain us more, thanks

Comment: @HakanKeles - We are waiting for your reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to know what link tag you want to modify with href. In the example I applied the first link tag using `.eq(0)` in jquery and use `.attr()` for set the href.

**Warning**:
you didn't specify the index means the attribute will applied for all your link tag in head.

```
var res = mobile ? 'mobil.css' : 'nonmobil.css';
$('link:eq(0)').attr('href', res)
```

Suppose you have to select 2nd link tag just use `.eq(1)`. it is working on array based index.

```
 $('link:eq(1)').attr('href', res)
```